# Include JQuery script to every CMS page within theme

Tags: magento2, cms, jquery

How can I include a JQuery script to every CMS page within a theme.

Placing the .js file in:

```
app/design/frontend/<company>/<theme>/web/js/file.js
```

and using script tags(below) in the CMS page doesnt work.

```
<script src="js/file.js">
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in the `local.xml` in your theme folder:

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>path/to/my/file.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

Comment: Where am I suppose to place this xml file? and does the file have a fixed filename I need to use?

Comment: You can write this code in local.xml in your theme folder

Comment: There was a no local.xml in my theme folder so I made one in <theme>/etc/local.xml, but its not included. Is there a command I should be running before it takes effect?